# Remote url with local asset on WkWebView

Tags: xamarin, wkwebview

I have following requirement from the client :

1) Load a remote webpage on iOS WKWebView.
2) Replace remote assets with files within the device/app local files

I am working on Xamarin Forms and have succeeded on similar requirement on Android plarform intercepting request using shouldInterceptRequest method but not sure how this requirement can be fulfilled on iOS platform.

After spending some time on internet I found all the cases local html file is loaded not the server url is being used.

Please let us know if this is feasible on iOS platform.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, you can save that  remote url to a local url html, replace all the local urls content, replace all the remote relative urls with remote full urls and run

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            webView.loadFileURL(localurl, allowingReadAccessTo: URL(string: LOCAL_FILES_DIRECTORY))
}
```

loadFileURL is not working for iOS8 and under.